# Sum column wise the min values of each row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to write the formula that sums for each column the values that are the minimum for each row.

I have a table like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | 4 |
| Sum of only min | 4 | 0 | 5 |

In the example, column A has 3 and 1 that are the minimum of row 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(BYCOL(IF(A1:C3=BYROW(A1:C3,LAMBDA(r,MIN(r))),A1:C3),LAMBDA(c,SUM(c))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this formula:

```
    =BYCOL(
MAP(A2:4,LAMBDA(e,IF(e=MIN(INDEX(A1:4,ROW(e))),e,IF(COUNTA(INDEX(A2:4,,COLUMN(e)))=0,"",0)))),
LAMBDA(each,IFERROR(SUM(each))))
```

[image]